# how to only sub the last space with dash in R

Tags: r, regex

how to only sub the last space with dash in R? In some cases, there are multi spaces (such as `aa`), but I'd like to only sub the last space with dash (such as `bb`). Code is as below:

```
aa <- c("Rapamycin 20nM", "Tributyltin chloride 100nM")
bb <- c("Rapamycin_20nM", "Tributyltin chloride_100nM")
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use something like `" (?=[^ ]+$)"` and `perl = TRUE`? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Or you could use `[ ]([^ ]*)$` replace '_$1' This would also replace a space at the beginning / end of string if it's the only one.

Comment: @JDB I tried with `sub(" (?=[^ ]+$)", "_\\1", aa, perl = TRUE)` and seem to be getting the desired output....

Comment: @JDB - there is _no_ regex engine that does _not_ allow variable length lookahead assertions.

Comment: @sln - Yeah, you're right. I was thinking of variable length lookbehind, which is supported in only a few engines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sub("(.*) ", "\\1_", aa)
[1] "Rapamycin_20nM"             "Tributyltin chloride_100nM"
```

Some details on the Regular Expression

`.` matches any character.  `.*` matches zero or more copies of any character. Putting the `.*` in parentheses saves the matching material for later use. 
Now the whole thing.  `(.*)` matches any number of characters followed by a blank. Because the matching is "greedy", it goes until the *last* blank. The string before the blank is saved so that when we write out the replacement,  we just duplicate the stuff before the blank and replace the blank with underscore.

Comment: This is definitely the easiest and most straightforward option.